# Prove that if $n|5^n + 8^n$, then $13|n$ using induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

I have to prove using mathematical induction that if $n \ge 2$ and $n|5^n + 8^n$, then $13|n$.

Please help me.

Comment: In fact, it seems that $n \mid 5^n + 8^n$ iff $n$ is a power of $13$.

Comment: And being a prime number, 13 will only divide $n$'s which have a power of 13 in their factorization. So you can write $n$ as $n=13k$ and $n+1=13k+1$ for the inductive step. Try it with $5^n+8^n$.

Comment: I tried it, but my result is $ 5(5^{13k} + 8^{13k}) + 3*8^{13k}  $
and the first component is divisible by 13k but I don't know what to do with the second component.

Comment: But $n+1 = 3k+1$ does *not* divide $5^{n+1} + 8^{n+1}$.  That is *doesn't* divide is what you want to prove.

Comment: @lhf : that is false. Perhaps it is because counterexamples are large that it may seem that way. It is not true that $ n | 5^n + 8^n $ iff $n$ is a power of $13$: for example, take $ n = 13*25169 $ . ( note $25169$ is prime, congruent to 1 mod 13, and divides $ 5^{13} + 8^{13} $ )

Comment: @Assaultous2, you're right! The first counterexample is $n=114413= 13^2 \cdot 677$.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A045597.

Comment: Followup: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811427/if-n-is-a-power-of-13-does-n-mid-5n-8n

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be the smallest prime natural number dividing $n$.  Clearly, $p$ is odd and $p\neq 5$.  Then, $\left(\frac{8}{5}\right)^{2n}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.  Hence, the order of $\frac{8}{5}$ divides $\gcd(2n,p-1)=2$.  Therefore, $\left(\frac{8}{5}\right)^2\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, leading to $p=3$ or $p=13$.  However, as $\frac{8}{5}\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, this removes the possibility that $p=3$.  As a result, $p=13$.

**P.S.:**  For any integer $m$ not divisible by $5$, interpret $\frac{8}{5}\mod m$ as the solution modulo $m$ to the congruence $5x\equiv 8\pmod{m}$.  I don't know how to approach this problem by induction.

Answer (score 1):

This is a provisional (correct) answer. I'm now on a possible right road to use induction as requested by the OP. I hope to use induction soon and give another answer (at least for me, this has been revealed somewhat difficult).

Let $$Q_n(a,b)=\frac{a^n+b^n}{a+b}=\sum_{k=0}^{k=n-1}a^k(-b)^{n-1-k}$$ The following elementary property is given in “13 Lectures on Fermat’s Last Theorem” by Paulo Ribenboim. Springer-Verlag. New York Heidelberg Berlin. page 52:
$$(Q_n(a,b),a+b)=(n,a+b)\qquad (1)$$ In our case we have $$(Q_n(5,8),13)=(n,13)\qquad (2)$$ Besides if $n|5^n+8^n$ then $n$ is clearly odd. It follows, assuming $n$ odd,
 $$5^n+8^n=13Q_n(5,8)\qquad (3)$$ Now, if  $(n,13)= 1$ then, by $(2)$,  $(Q_n(5,8),13)=1$ then, by $(3)$, $n$ does not divide $5^n+8^n$.

It follows that $n$ and $13$ are not coprime hence $n$ is a multiple of the prime $13$ (equivalently $13|n$).

REMARK.- If $13$ divides $5^n+8^n$ then $13^2$ divides $5^n+8^n$. Calculation gives the smallest example $n\gt 1$ for which $n$ divides $5^n+8^n$ is $n=13$; in fact one has 
$$5^{13}+8^{13}=13^2\cdot 3 260 216 077$$